# Buffer is not reading in string properly

Tags: c, file, sockets, networking, buffer

```
void download(char *file)
{
    int size = getsize(file);
    printf("Got size %d\n", size);
    sprintf(buff, "GET %s\n", file);
    send(sockfd, buff, strlen(buff), 0);
    rsize = recv(sockfd, buff, 1000, 0);
    sscanf(buff, "%d", &resultcode);
    printf("%s",  buff);
    if (strcmp(buff, "+OK\n") != 0)
    {
        printf("download failed\n");
    }
    FILE *dlfile = NULL;
    if ((dlfile = fopen(file, "r")) != NULL)
    {
        dlfile = fopen(file, "w");
        do
        {
            rsize = recv(sockfd, buff, 1000, 0);
            for (int i = 0; i < rsize; i++)
            {
                fprintf(dlfile, "%c", buff[i]);
            }
            size = size - rsize;
        } while (size != 0);
    }
    fclose(dlfile);
}
```

I am trying to make the download function print out contents of file user typed, then save it to their current directory. I did a debug line `printf("%s", buff);` and it prints out `+OK\n(filename)`. It is supposed to print out `+OK\n`. It also prints out `download failed` then a `segmentation fault` error. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you comparing  `+OK\n(filename)` with "+OK\n"? they are not equal. Are you looking for `strstr`?

Comment: Your assuming all that is sitting on that socket is "OK\n" when you read it. Methinks the sender is stuffing it right after they throw the response up. And for all the is good in this world, **check your function call return values.**. Only the foolhardy spit in the face of [Henry Spencer's Sixth Commandment for C Programmers](http://www.seebs.net/c/10com.html)

Answer (score 0):

Several things going on here.  First, recv and send basically operate on arrays of bytes so they do not know about line endings and such.  Also note that recv is not guaranteed to fill the buffer - it generally reads what is available up to the limit of the buffer.  For your strcmp against "+OK\n", you could use strncmp with a length of 4 but that is a bit direct (see below). Next note that the buff string is not null terminated by recv so your printf could easily crash.

When you go in to your loop, the buffer already has part of the rest of your I/O in it.  May include other fields or parts of the file.  You need to process it as well. It is not clear to me what getsize does - but using that size to drive your loop seems off.  Also, your loop to fprintf the values can be replaced by a call to fwrite.

Overall, you need to properly buffer and then parse the incoming stream of data.   If you want to do it yourself, you could look at fdopen to get a FILE object.